# How to calculate the limit inferior of this set sequence?

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I started reading [Probability & Measure Theory by Robert Ash and Catherine Doleans-Dade](https://www.elsevier.com/books/probability-and-measure-theory/ash/978-0-08-051487-1) and got stuck at the second exercise in the very first section.

> Define sets of real numbers as follows. Let $A_n=(-1/n, 1]$ if $n$ is
>   odd, and $A_n=(-1, 1/n]$ if $n$ is even. Find $\lim\sup_n A_n$ and
>   $\lim\inf_n A_n$ (limit superior and limit inferior).

I got the correct solution for $\lim\sup_n A_n$ (it is $(-1, 1]$), but it seems that I'm making some mistake(s) for $\lim\inf_n$.

Here's my solution:
$$
\begin{matrix}
A_1=(-1, 1] & A_2 = (-1, 1/2] \\
A_3 = (-1/3, 1] & A_4 = (-1, 1/4] \\
A_5 = (-1/5, 1] &A_6 = (-1, 1/6] \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
A_{2k+1} = (\frac{-1}{(2k+1)}, 1] & A_{2k}=(-1, \frac 1 {2k}] \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\end{matrix}
$$
We can see that $A_1 \supset A_3 \supset  A_5 \supset \ldots$ and $A_2 \supset A_4 \supset A_6 \supset \ldots$.

We can also see that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}A_{2k} = (-1, 0]$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}A_{2k+1}=(0, 1]$.

From there, I concluded that $$\bigcap_{even\ k \geq n}^{\infty}A_k=(-1, 0]$$ and $$\bigcap_{odd\ k \geq n}^{\infty}A_{k}=(0, 1]$$ for each $n$, and got the following result:

$$
\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_n=\left(\bigcap_{even\ k \geq n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{odd\ k \geq n}^{\infty}A_{k}\right) = (-1, 0] \cap (0, 1] = \emptyset
$$

So:
$$
\lim\inf_n A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\emptyset=\emptyset
$$

However, the correct answer listed at the end of the book is $\{0\}$.

Would anyone be so kind to check my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim A_{2k+1}=[0,1]$. Note that $0 \in A_{2k+1}$ for each $k$.

[The intervals are open on the left but that doesn't mean that you have to leave out $0$ in the limit. You have to include it because $0 \in A_{2k+1}$ for each $k$].

Comment: Is zero included because the interval shrinks from the left and $0$ is contained in each $A_{2k+1}$, no matter the interval being open at that end? What confused me was that $A_{2k+1}=(-1/(2k+1), 1]$, but the limit's closed on the left. However, I think I get it now. If you could expand your answer a bit on that part (for me and future readers who may make the same mistake), I'll accept it right away.